# get_queried_object() returns null on post date archive

Tags: wp-query

`get_queried_object()` returns `null` on post date archives (page type `is_date()`) and the main blog index page (page type `is_home()`). Is this intentional, or just an oversight?

I was writing a wrapper around get_queried_object() to get the title of the current page, no matter what type of page it is, for use in a theme. I quickly realized that instead of using `get_query_object()` I should just duplicate the important bits from [`wp_title()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L541), but before that I came across an interesting issue.

It appears that `get_queried_object()` and its root function [`WP_Query->get_queried_object()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/query.php#L3246) return `null` for a couple of listing types, including the primary posts list output by index.php (page type `is_home()`) and post archives by date (page type `is_date()`).

I tested this by throwing the following snippet into a number of template files in a number of locations, always after `get_header()` and before `the_post()`:

```
<pre><code><?php
    $queried_object = get_queried_object();
    var_dump( $queried_object );
?></code></pre>
```

This works perfectly on category archives, tag archives, custom taxonomy archives, and custom post type archives. `get_queried_object()` returns the query object, which can be used to extract a page title and other useful information.

However, it fails in archive.php for standard post date archives and index.php for the normal blog posts home page list view.

Digging into [the source of `WP_Query->get_queried_object()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/query.php#L3246) reveals something rather unsurprising: there is no check for page type `is_home()` or page type `is_date()`, so on those page types `$this->queried_object = null;` is not updated and the function returns `null`.

So my question is, is this intended functionality (e.g. are you not supposed to use get_queried_object() on those pages), a technical limitation (is there not a meaningful object to return on those pages), or simply an implementation oversight?

Is there even an equivalent of the custom post type object for the built-in "blog post" post type to display?

Comment: Great point +. WordPress could do something to create an object for those date archive and front page _italic_(note: it do return an object if blog page is set to a wordpress page, not the front page)_italic_ . But at the end, there's no meaningful use of `get_queried_object`.

Comment: I don't know how to answer this question,r eally, but yes, `get_queried_object` is very inconsistent and returns several different objects as well as sometimes returning `null`. While it is useful, it can be frustrating to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> so my question is, is this intended functionality (e.g. are you not
> supposed to use get_queried_object() on those pages), a technical
> limitation (is there not a meaningful object to return on those
> pages), or simply an implementation oversight?

get_queried_object() is to get the term, author, single post, single custom post type, or page object being queried.  Yes this is intentional and what this function was designed to do.

If you are on a date archive, home page, or search there is no single object being queried.

### Edit:

Based on the first comment below the OP needs to get the post_type object.  The post_type object is different from the queried_object.  If you need to get the post_type object on an archive page you can get it from the query_vars.

```
global $wp_query;

$post_type_object = get_post_type_object( $wp_query->query_vars['post_type'] );
```

Comment: This is irritating; if there is something meaningful to return for custom post type archive pages (the custom post type object), why shouldn't something similar return for the standard post post type archive pages? I suppose this can probably be explained by WP's history as a more focused blogging engine, but is there any good reason that build-in post types should get this kind of special treatment, and should not be given the functionality to handle just like custom types? I think it'd be more useful if custom types could be more easily mixed with builtin types.

Comment: There are other ways to get what you want.  get_queried_object is applicable ONLY if the request is a category, author, permalink or Page. Holds information on the requested category, author, post or Page. The query_vars hold everything else.

Comment: Then my confusion is the functionality of `get_queried_object()` on custom post type archive pages but not on standard post archive pages. If `get_queried_object()` returns the post type object on custom post type archive and index pages, then I would think it only logical to return the post type object on standard post archive and index pages. I will accept the situation if it's simply like that for historical reasons and the special handling of the built-in post types is for backwards-compatibility, but I would like an explanation.

Comment: i think there is meaningfull information that would be great to have:

what year/month/day is queried,
posts count/max_num_pages

Comment: also note that on author archive pages `get_queried_object()` returns a `WP_User` Object while on term based archives it returns a `WP_Term` Object - so one need first to sanitize returns of `get_queried_object()` to use in a generic archive template - and a `WP_Date` Object is missing.

since in the default themes achive.php the date title uses `get_the_date()` and that uses `get_post()` it only represents the date of the first post shown and it logically just works but it does not exactly represent the query and bases on that everything else works as expected.

Comment: I think it's an oversight, and should probably have a trac ticket with a patch, if anyone is interested in making one.

Comment: @Chris_O ~ "If you are on a date archive, home page, or search there is no single object being queried." is that the complete list? There is not much documentation on it.