# How to get the real address from a url (permalink)

Tags: plugins, url-rewriting, urls, query-string

For some reason i need the actual address of current page in my plugin , but after searching i can not find any answer on how i can get the real address of current page.
I tested many functions for example `url_to_postid`.
But this function returns 0 in categories , archives and many other links , and this only works for posts and pages.
What i want is a `url` with its query strings (even if user is using custom permalinks).
How i can get that in a plugin ?

Comment: It would be helpful to explain what exactly you're trying to do rather than ask about what you think the solution to your problem is.

Comment: Hi, i want let user makes some changes in any page of his site . my plugin editor is working in frontend and plugin sends data to server and stores them. now i want detect page address to save that data for only that page.

Comment: you probably want something like [`get_queried_object`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) then.

Comment: This function is nice , it works in  many places , but also returns null in some pages ! look at this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128685/get-queried-object-returns-null-on-post-date-archive . thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

have you looked at `$_SERVER`

```
 $real_address = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
 echo $real_address;
```

This code grabs your url with it's parameters and saves it to the `$real_address` variable

Also have a look at this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. but REQUEST_URI returns the permalink . what i want is wordpress default url. for example site.com/?p=12 or site.com/?cat=2 .

Comment: you can just reset the permalink to default then.

Comment: Also have you tried the get_the_guid() function?

Comment: I have no access to users wp installation , also this is a rewrited url , i think it is possible to get the real url.

Comment: I tested get_the_guid() but it not works for archives.

Comment: for archives we have the get_post_type_archive_link( $post_type ) function but i don't think it will give you the real WP address you are looking for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19611/discussion-between-f-n174-and-karun).

Answer (score -1):

You should use `$_SERVER[]` global array to get the url of the page.

The simplified syntax is:

```
$request_url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

You can then use the variable `$request_url` where you need the url.